# read a file and redirect it to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Im trying to find a file with x type and store that in a variable. It is working fine when i try to execute manually. If the same i tried using that in bash script it is displaying `test_count='1` because of this if condition is failing.

Please find the command below

```
usage_backup_dir=/test/usage_backup
DT_FILENAME=$(date +%Y%m%d); export DT_FILENAME

test_count=$(find $usage_backup_dir -type f -name "Summary_$DT_FILENAME*.bdm_all_cases.lg.log" -exec cat {} + )
echo $test_count
```

Comment: usage_backup_dir=/test/usage_backup this is the variable im passing in the script

Comment: Does `$DT_FILENAME` have a value in your test and real scenarios?

Comment: Yes @roaima it is a variable im passing in the script DT_FILENAME=`date +%Y%m%d`; export DT_FILENAME

Comment: If it displays the literal string `test_count='1`, then that's the contents of the file(s) that were found and outputted into your variable `test_count`.

Comment: I verified but the file just have the number like 1

Comment: I verified and i don't see any special characters in that file.